# single-spa with multiple versions of same library(React) or Framework, How to handle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-spa-angular, single-spa

I have been going through single-spa from past few days, and it is very simple to setup and integrate the frmawork(Angualar) apps or libraries(React/redux app).

But I have one doubt though

```
{
  "name": "single-spa-simple-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    ...
    "single-spa": "^4.3.4",
    "single-spa-react": "^2.10.2",
    "single-spa-vue": "^1.4.0",
    "single-spa-angular":"4.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js -p"
  },
```

Consider today I have 10 or more React apps, and couple months after I need to work on latest React app (for ex: React-18), then how to include that project in this existing single-spa project, as we have only one package.json file and one node_modules folder, we can not have two different versions of same package name in package.json file.

And I do not want to work on the existing React App.

1. The existing Apps should run in the same version it was built, and the new React versioned App should also Run. is this possible in single-spa ?
2. If single SPA has one package.json file, I have one more doubt, consider I have a simple app having react-16 and angular9 app, and for some reason, I want a libray say XYZ , for both React and angular projects , But they want differnt versions of X.js
3. Do any one has implemention idea like

```
Single-SPA
   |-AngularApp1
   |    | /src
   |    |-node_modules
   |    |-package.json (version 6)
   |
   |-AngularApp2
   |    | /src
   |    |-node_modules
   |    |-package.json  (version 9)
   |
   |-React
   |    | /src
   |    |-node_modules
   |    |-package.json
```

Comment: Have you read about "Shared Dependencies" in the docs? https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#shared-dependencies

Comment: It's a good read but it doesn't address the main question of how to use different versions of the package, although their main point to only load big dependencies once is really valid, using multiple versions of the big dependency like React might be very bad for performance.

Comment: I see in the example repo that they do use multiple versions for different views, still that has consequences on the amount of code a user has to download (despite code splitting) but that might be worth it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how that doesn't solve the issue? "Using multiple versions of a framework" basically meaning having each app bundle their own deps. This is how bundlers work, they namespace everything per build. Then if you want to share a dependency, you use the importmaps that the recommended setup talks about.

Comment: Webpack 5, now had Module Federation to organise and create a micro frontend file structure and it has options for dependency sharing or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem faced when working with microfrontends, though there isn't a clear cut best solution.

Indeed, you would need to split your source code into multiple NPM packages with their own package.json to allow different apps to have different versions of dependencies (React, XYZ lib). You can then compile each app into a bundle and launch those bundles in Single-Spa. But there are still challenges. Your total site bundle size will grow since you are now not fully able to share the dependencies that are the same. You also still cannot run multiple React apps in the same view at once if they don't use the same version of React.

There are also tools to help with some of this, like Lerna but you might not need that complexity yet. 
There are also other ways to create microfrontends, such as microservices that return server side rendered HTML so the integration doesn't need to happen in build time like with Single-Spa but rather at runtime. This, as everything else, has pros and cons.

So you might consider, is it really worth it to run multiple different versions of React? Perhaps it's better both for your users and your developers to instead try to upgrade to the latest versions in the older apps. Since they are microfrontends they should be smaller which means that upgrade should be easier. This also achieves that your bundle to download is smaller and you don't need more backend infrastructure. But you do need to collaborate across all apps to upgrade at the same time. Each approach has its own challenge.

Comment: Re: "You also still cannot run multiple React apps in the same view at once if they don't use the same version of React" This is incorrect. Importmap scopes help with this exact case: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/import-maps.md#scopes
With a proper setup, you can have multiple versions of a framework. This is especially good when upgrading to a major version and want to give teams time to migrate.

Comment: I see, that is true but that wouldn't run two apps in the same view, that would be two different views. React itself will throw errors if it detects two versions of React loaded in the same view/page and that is a feature that Single-Spa supports, to run two apps side by side.

Comment: Right, I was speaking more broadly. That React warns when detecting multiple versions is not the case for many libraries, and should be able to be used without issue.

Comment: @filoxo I haven't been able to get Importmap scopes to work. I've tried root path's such as /iam/ and full paths such as http://localhost:8080/iam.  It just doesn't recognize the packages defined for the scope.